# Twitter 2 for Android crash every time I try uploading multi photos

Tags: twitter

I'm using the new Twitter 2 on Android 2.1.

Whenever I hit the button which enables me to upload multiple photos in a single tweet, I always get the error "The application Camera (process com.sonyericsson.camera) has stopped unexpectidly. Please try again". However, uploading a single photo using the camera button in Twitter have no problem, it works.

My phone is Sony Ericsson x10 mini pro.

I tried signing out and back in, same result.

Anything I can do to fix this?

This is the log info I got using Log Collector:

```
02-23 15:05:57.328 I/ActivityManager( 1240): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.twitter.android.post.status cmp=com.twitter.android/.PostActivity }
02-23 15:05:57.338 D/PhoneWindow(15095): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45726938 has no id.
02-23 15:05:57.688 I/ActivityManager( 1240): Displayed activity com.twitter.android/.PostActivity: 340 ms (total 340 ms)
02-23 15:05:59.018 I/ActivityManager( 1240): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/image cmp=com.sonyericsson.camera/com.sonyericsson.album.grid.GridActivity }
02-23 15:05:59.038 I/ActivityManager( 1240): Start proc com.sonyericsson.camera for activity com.sonyericsson.camera/com.sonyericsson.album.grid.GridActivity: pid=15113 uid=10057 gids={1006, 1015, 3003}
02-23 15:05:59.128 I/dalvikvm(15113): Debugger thread not active, ignoring DDM send (t=0x41504e4d l=38)
02-23 15:05:59.158 I/dalvikvm(15113): Debugger thread not active, ignoring DDM send (t=0x41504e4d l=50)
02-23 15:05:59.448 I/ActivityManager( 1240): Displayed activity com.sonyericsson.camera/com.sonyericsson.album.grid.GridActivity: 423 ms (total 423 ms)
02-23 15:05:59.458 W/dalvikvm(15113): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e160)
02-23 15:05:59.458 E/AndroidRuntime(15113): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported MIME type.
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at com.sonyericsson.album.grid.GridActivity$AlbumTask.doInBackground(GridActivity.java:202)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at com.sonyericsson.album.grid.GridActivity$AlbumTask.doInBackground(GridActivity.java:124)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-23 15:05:59.468 E/AndroidRuntime(15113):     ... 4 more
02-23 15:05:59.628 E/SemcCheckin(15113): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
02-23 15:05:59.628 W/ActivityManager( 1240): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.sonyericsson.android.jcrashcatcher.action.BUGREPORT_AUTO cmp=com.sonyericsson.android.jcrashcatcher/.JCrashCatcherService (has extras) }: not found
02-23 15:05:59.648 I/Process ( 1240): Sending signal. PID: 15113 SIG: 3
02-23 15:05:59.648 I/dalvikvm(15113): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-23 15:05:59.778 I/dalvikvm(15113): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-23 15:06:00.388 E/SemcCheckin( 1673): Get Crash Level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
02-23 15:06:01.708 I/DumpStateReceiver( 1240): Added state dump to 1 crashes
02-23 15:06:02.008 D/iddd-events( 1117): Registering event com.sonyericsson.idd.probe.android.devicemonitor::ApplicationCrash with 4314 bytes payload.
02-23 15:06:06.968 D/dalvikvm( 1673): GC freed 661 objects / 126704 bytes in 124ms
02-23 15:06:11.928 D/dalvikvm( 1379): GC freed 19753 objects / 858832 bytes in 84ms
02-23 15:06:13.038 I/Process (15113): Sending signal. PID: 15113 SIG: 9
02-23 15:06:13.048 I/WindowManager( 1240): WIN DEATH: Window{4596ecc0 com.sonyericsson.camera/com.sonyericsson.album.grid.GridActivity paused=false}
02-23 15:06:13.048 I/ActivityManager( 1240): Process com.sonyericsson.camera (pid 15113) has died.
02-23 15:06:13.048 I/WindowManager( 1240): WIN DEATH: Window{459db5e8 com.sonyericsson.camera/com.sonyericsson.album.grid.GridActivity paused=false}
02-23 15:06:13.078 I/UsageStats( 1240): Unexpected resume of com.twitter.android while already resumed in com.sonyericsson.camera
02-23 15:06:13.098 W/InputManagerService( 1240): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@456e7168
02-23 15:06:21.278 D/dalvikvm( 1745): GC freed 2032 objects / 410848 bytes in 60ms
```

Comment: Make sure you also send the error log to the developer and what you did to produce it.

Comment: I'm guessing Twitter just doesn't play with your camera nicely.  They probably never tested on an x10 Mini.  So I agree with Brian, contact them.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the x10 have very unique camera software (an original interface for viewing pictures)? I wouldn't know because I don't have one, but I thought that was the case. It looks like the camera software has some sort of bug at lines 124 and 202 in its GridActivity. Sending this error report to the manufacturer (Sony) along with how you got it (like Bryan Denny said) would be very helpful to them. Unfortunately, it looks like its one photo at a time for now.

Comment: I contacted Twitter support and sent them the Log file I got. I hope it won't take them long time to fix it. Thanks every one.